# Create one email with cell values from all relevant rows as the mail body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an Excel file with 1000+ rows. There is data in column A, addressee 1 email in column M, addressee 2 email in column N and validation column O.

Validation column mechanism: If the value in the cell is <0 then the row should be taken into the email.

I need a macro to draft one email and the content of email should be merged table of all rows that have negative value in column O (key).
The email should be adressed via Bcc to email addresses from column M and Cc to email addresses in column N.
The subject and content of the email is not that important, but I'd like to adjust it. For the purpose of the exercise it can be "Generic title", "Generic Content".

After the email is drafted, I need to click "send" in Outlook.
After sending an email for a row, the value in column O for this row should change to a green cell with "OK" value.

**DUMMY DATA BEFORE MACRO RUN**
[image]

**THE MAIL**
[image]

**DUMMY DATA AFTER MACRO RUN**
[image]

The code below creates a seperate email for each row instead of one email with cell values from column A combined in one table (or some other form) as the email body. How do I re-arrange it so it creates one email?

```vb
Sub Send_mails()
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell as Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    For Each cell in Worksheets("test1"). Columns("O").Cells
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            With OutMail
                .Bcc = Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value
                .Cc = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value
                .Subject = "Gneric Subject"
                .Body = "Generic body text, Values from column A for each row meeting the condition, to be put here"
                .display
            End With
            Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value = "OK"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Put some dummy data and the example of the bulk mail format.

Comment: Added :) Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understood what you need!
From your dummy data I **created a table** and named it **tbClient**.
Here is the code and the mail output!
You need to **set a Reference** to Microsoft Word or you change the code to use Late Binding.

```
Option Explicit

Public ws As Worksheet
Public ol As ListObject
Public olRng As Range

Sub copyTabletoEmail()
    Dim olCol As Integer
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Set ws = Sheets("Test1")
    Set ol = ws.ListObjects("tbClient")
   
    ' remove table filter buttons
    If Not ol.ShowAutoFilterDropDown Then ol.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = True
   
    ' clear table filters
    If ol.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then ol.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
   
    ' get validation column
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Validation").Index
       
    ' filter table
    ol.Range.AutoFilter field:=olCol, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlOr
   
    ' remove table filter buttons
    ol.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
   
    ' select table to copy
    Set olRng = ol.Range
   
    ' create mail
    Call CreateMail
    
   ' Change values on 'Validation' column
    ol.ListColumns(olCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "OK"
    
    ' clear table filters
    If ol.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then ol.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
   
Sub CreateMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim OutInsp As Object
    Dim mailTo As String, mailCC As String
   
    Dim olCol As Integer
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim addRng As Range
   
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' display mail
    OutMail.display
   
    ' If you're sending the same message to everyone the next 2 lines can be moved outside of the loop
    OutMail.Subject = "Generic Subject"
   
    ' Range of mail addresses
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Client mail").Index
    Set addRng = ol.ListColumns(olCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   
    ' get the mail addresses
    For Each rCell In addRng
        With OutMail
             mailTo = mailTo & rCell.Value & ";"
             mailCC = mailCC & rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"
        End With
    Next rCell
   
    OutMail.to = mailTo
    OutMail.cc = mailCC
   
    ' Declare word Variables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWdEditor As Word.Editors
   
    ' Get the Active Inspector
    Set OutInsp = OutMail.GetInspector
   
    ' Get the document within the inspector
    Set oWrdDoc = OutInsp.WordEditor
       
    ' Greetings
    Dim bodyMessage As String
    bodyMessage = "Hi Kapcer," & vbNewLine
    oWrdDoc.Range.InsertBefore bodyMessage
    
    ' Paste the table
    olRng.Copy
    oWrdDoc.Range(Len(bodyMessage), Len(bodyMessage)).Paste
    
exitRoutine:
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' clear
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    ' Open immediate window to see the error
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    
    Resume exitRoutine
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Elio, many thanks for helping me out!
The code makes sense to me, however I get an error "Run time error '9': Subscript out of range" for "Sub copyTabletoEmail() and after clicking "debug" , it highlights the "Set ol = ws.ListObjects("tbClient")", do you have  hunch what might be the underlying issue?

Comment: And to clarify, I need to:


I need to:
1) Filter the table only fot the rows that meet the condition: cell value in "Validation" column is <0
2) Create an outlook mail & copy the table to email
3) Bcc the email to all adresses from column "client email" & CC to all "Contrahent mail" from filtered table
4) Set value to "OK" for all cells in "Validation" in filtered table in excel
5) Clear the filters

Comment: I told that I converted you data range into a table and named it 'tbClient'. Try to convert your table into a table and change the name to 'tbClient' or change the name in the code to the named of the table you just created. The code I posted works well.

Comment: To make sure & test the code work, I re-created the dummy table in excel & run your exact code.
I got an error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With Block variable not set. The empty mail pops out - the mail has proper title, but there are no adresees & no table in the content.
While debugging, the VBA highlights for me the line "olCol = ol.ListColumns("Client mail").Index

Do you know what might be an issue? I hoped that if I copy the code 1:1, then I'll get the resultemail  you got in the screen you attached.

Comment: The error can be due to the incorrect name of the column name 'client mail' or the variable olCol does not exist. If none of this, do you have a dropbox where you can share the file with code I posted and your dummy table?

Comment: Hi @Elio Fernandes I double checked the spelling & variables and they seem fine. Sending you the file with code & the table: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/p3zuv4o5a0pftfnlvuq8b/Dummy_data.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=elnmiv1o0lk0rl6fklnn7drw2

Comment: Hi Kacper. What I call a table is not what you send me. A table is an object that is dynamic and very easy to wok with after you learn. Here is a link where you can see the basics on how to work with a table: https://exceljet.net/excel-tables. I converted your dummy table into a table object and it works just fine! How an I send you the file back to you?

Comment: Here is your file https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm52yq50q3fybix/Dummy_data.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Elio Many thanks for the file & for the tables explanation :) However, when I run your code on the file you sent (table is now table), I still get the same errors/results (mail without adressees & without table + "olCol = ol.ListColumns("Client mail").Index" debugging issues) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o1vmy2vela3p7t8/AACUcaaPrdkSJMxPXO3D49sta?dl=0

How did you manage to get the results from your screen (proper mail) with your code on this file? I just can't wrap my head around it

Comment: I jus tried again the file I shared in the dropbox and it works withou errors. I just added some error handling in the mail function so that you can see the error in the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks, you're the man Elio! :)
Creating email & pasting the table now works fine. 
Do you know how can  those cells from  "Validation" column in excel worksheet be updated to "OK" after the email is created & table copied. So that after the original filtered table is copied to email, in excel the all the negative values are changed i.e. from "-202" to "OK"?

I played around & tried to add "Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value = "OK" " to your code, but didn't really work for me.

Comment: I just updated the file! All the negative values of 'Validation' column changes to 'OK' after CreateMail as run. Do not forget to put a check on this answer if it was useful.

Comment: It worked! Mnay thanks :) Of course I put a check on the answer!

Comment: BTW. @Elio is it possible to paste into mail only particular columns from the table (not the whole tbClient table) i.e. columns only B, F,G,H,I/ Columns "Valid", "Client email",... etc.  ?
I tried to adress it by "Copy Range("B,F,G,H,I"), but didn't work for me.

Also, is it possible to put the current date value into column R, after the mail is created? (Value to be put there only for the rows that were pasted into mail)

Comment: You should to try to understand the code I already posted, running the code step by step using F8.  I going to give you some hints! Create a new column 'Sent On'. Look at the code and when the table is filtered to be copied to the mail, insert the date in the column you just created. The simplest way to paste only the desired columns to the mail, is to hide the others that you don't want. You can record a macro to hide the columns and then do some changes to show them again. A more complex way is by using advanced filters. Let me know what you achieved.

Comment: Hi @Elio - thanks for the tips! I managed to add the hiding/unhiding - the tricky part was to do it as a part of Sub CreateMail () instead of Sub copyTabletoEmail().
I also managed to insert the date into the column I wanted.
Now the only thing I have left is to add some text to the body mail before the table.
I tried to put :

OutMail.Body = "Hi All, please find...." after the OutMail.Subject = "Generic Subject".
However it didn't work, probably because of the table copying/pasting mechanism. Do you have some tips how I can add the text to the mail body?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send a single email, cc'd to all of the recipients in column N and bcc'd to all of the recipients in column M, then use logic like this:

```
Sub Send_mails()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Recipient as Object
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim cell as Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test1")   ' Assuming ThisWorkbook is correct
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

For Each cell in ws.Columns("O").Cells     ' Better to limit this to the used range so you don't loop over 1 million rows.
    If cell.Value < 0 Then
        With OutMail
             Set Recipient = .Recipients.Add(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value
             Recipient.Type = olBcc
             Set Recipient = .Recipients.Add(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value
             Recipient.Type = olCc

             ' If you're sending the same message to everyone the next 2 lines can be moved outside of the loop
             .Subject = "Gneric Subject"
             .Body = "Generic body text, Values from column A for each row meeting the condition, to be put here"
        End With
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value = "OK"
    End If
Next Cell
OutMail.display
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set Recipient = Nothing
Set OutApp as Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

I haven't run this, so there could be bugs.

Comment: Thank you, it helps. 
Nevertheless, my main obstacle is putting the values of the cells from column A  (that meets the requirement : " For Each cell in ws.Columns("O").Cells   
    If cell.Value < 0 Then)") into the mail's body content.

So for example:
row 1 meets the requirement (cell 1O value <0) -->Cell A1 value is put in the mail's body.
Row 2 does not meet the requirement --> cell A2 is skipped
Row 3 does meet the req --> Cell A3 value is put in the mail's body (together with A1 value), etc.

Do you have an idea how to handle that?

Comment: If believe you can also make the changes by yourself. Take a look at this video https://youtu.be/f8s-jY9y220?t=4161. Let me know if you were successful!

Comment: Hi Elio, thanks for the material! I tried the methods he shown in the video. However, each time I tried to put those greetings into the body (be it via variable, or "hardcode"), the excel table was pasted on top of the greetings & the greetings weren't visible in the body.
I tried to use InsertBefore & defining the range for the greetings but still didn't work with my/your code. Do you have an idea how to work this around?

Comment: I updated the code I posted above. See sub CreateMail, after 'Greetings'. It's just a small example.